# how to get file without as it is

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to read a html file and store its content but when I am converting it I am Getting all the special characters are converted to Question mark.

I am using stream reader to read the file and stream writer to write the content of that file to another file after storing the content in the Database.

Comment: -1 because no code is shown. Show us some code, an example of what's happening, what you want it to look like. We aren't mind readers...

Comment: Are you specifying any encoding for the reader ?, show the relevant code

Comment: No  i am not specifying encoding for the reader.I just want to know which encoding is good for the reader when I am reading a html file

Comment: What is the encoding used in the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to specify `System.Text.Encoding` for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. I assuming that in most cases you should use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`. Also I assuming you use NVARCHAR (not VARCHAR) in DB?